# python - pip is not working after upgrade

Tags: pip, ubuntu-14.04, python-3.4

I tried upgrade pip3 with this command:

> sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip

but unfortunately it doesn't work anymore and shows this message:

> pip3 --version

message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 651, in _build_master
>       ws.require(**requires**)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 952, in require
>       needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 844, in resolve
>       raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req) pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 7.1.2
>   (/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages),
>   Requirement.parse('pip==1.5.6'))
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in 
>       from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3084, in 
>       @_call_aside
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3070, in _call_aside
>       f(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 3097, in _initialize_master_working_set
>       working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 653, in _build_master
>       return cls._build_from_requirements(**requires**)
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 666, in _build_from_requirements
>       dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 839, in resolve
>       raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==1.5.6' distribution was
>   not found and is required by the application

How to fix it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It seems like you don't use `virtualenv` and your pythons/paths are probably messed up.
I faced with similar problem with python-2.7 and -3.4 on Ubuntu 14.04. I tried

```
sudo python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```

for 2.7 and it helped. Then I reinstalled `pip` for python-3.4 via `easy_install3`.

Comment: Thanks, easy_install pip solve the probleme for pip3. Very nice.